# What does “official police issue” mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I came across this sentence [on the television crime drama](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMj_YtyWLRM) *Rizzoli & Isles*. In the scene, A introduced B to C, and said to C that

> B is a detective with the Boston Police Department.

After taking a look at B's dress, C said to B,

> Oh. And is that official police issue?

My question is what does **official police issue** mean here?

Comment: "And is that dress officially issued to police?"

Comment: Shouldn't it be `And is that dress officially issued by the (Boston) Police department?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll answer as the relevant dictionary definition of *[issue](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/issue)* (MW) may not be obvious:

> 9 a:  the act of publishing or officially giving out or making available
>
> > the next issue of commemorative stamps
> >     issue of supplies by the quartermaster
>
> b:  the thing or the whole quantity of things given out at one time
>
> > read the latest issue

*Police issue* would be the standard tools, weapons, clothing, and other supplies which the police force provides to its members. Stock army equipment provided to soldiers is similarly *[army issue](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/army-issue)*.

This particular example is a clichéd joke, in which someone wryly asks if something outlandish or obviously not standard is, in fact, *[standard issue](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/standard%20issue)*.